# iptables use to ignore TCP packets. Not reject But ignoring including syc comning in but nothing is done

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, linux-kernel, c

I like to simulate TCP connection in Server-client using layer 2 sockets for receiving packets and sending packets using Packet MMAP or DPDK or netfilters and dev_xmit for this to come any close to any any some working phase, I need no interference. So the server program and and client running on virtual machines can can connect through simulated TCP -- I will keep adding TCP features over time starting with connection creation and maintaining sequence numbers and 4 way shutdown handshake . Actually the program that I like to try to transmit data so It can be big files and many of them like over hundreds in numbers. this whole thing is just for checking can I achieve this functionality in linux which believe it can be -- please mention if i AM wrong . So like to know does this task makes sense

On this page https://blog.cloudflare.com/kernel-bypass/ it talks about kernel bypass methods in Linux. But I like to try one of them to see if TCP can be simulated. I am familiar with these program and resources Packet MMAP https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.14.32/source/tools/testing/selftests/net

PACKET MMAP and DPDK on kernel.org for network stack Please note I also need to know to ignore TCP packets can anything be done in IPtables or something to achieve the above

Comment: if it need certain features disabled when compiling and building kernel then please tell me which features and impact of disabling them. Thanks

Comment: like to see loopback interface keep working after doing anything